# Server error for non-diamonds when attempting to look at some old election pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, 500-server-error, nominations

When I attempt to access the "Nomination" phase of an election which has concluded, I get the "Oops! Something Bad Happened" page. This happens both on sites which I am a member of and on those of which I am not. I get the page both when navigating by direct link (e.g. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=nomination) or when clicking on the tab from the main election page:

[image: election phase tabs: Nomination, Primary, Election, with the nomination tab circled]

From a (Discord) conversation with a CM, it seems that she could see the tab, but only when logged in. The other two tabs, "Primary" and "Election", work fine for me. I discovered the bug when attempting to read nomination comments for an old election I had stumbled across. Notably, since [comments are only displayed within "Nomination"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222078/comments-on-moderator-nomination-statements-should-be-more-visible-in-all-stages), this means I am *completely unable to access any election comments* for old elections which weren't cancelled; such comments are often useful to understand a site's context at a certain point in time.

Per comments, this is also happening for several entire elections, e.g. Freelancing's two elections with candidates and Community Building's single one.

Comment: I'm very confident that this is due to a withdrawn nomination (more rarely, it may have been a withdrawn nomination by a now-deleted user). CM's (but not, to my knowledge, site moderators) can see those, which would allow the CM you were speaking with to see it when she was logged in.

Comment: Hrmph. Lame. I might be completely incorrect. Simply browsing the [one and only CommunityBuilding.SE election](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/election/1) throws a 500 server error. I don't believe they had a withdrawn nomination there. More interestingly, [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/election) had an election in which nobody nominated, and navigating to that election at all throws the error for me as well.

Comment: Reproduced. Worth noting that I *can*, however, view that tab on sites where I have a diamond. On sites that I don't I get an error.

Comment: @Spevacus: Looks like that Community Building election was canceled (and the one candidate appointed). That Sound Design election was also canceled... I can access both while logged in.

Comment: The nomination tab is broken for *every* election, at least for every ended one. Just try going one-by-one on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination

Comment: Interestingly, the nomination pages still work for moderators, so it must be an access/privilege-level issue.

Comment: @Adam, should I be expecting an answer with juicy debugging deets? :)

Comment: @bobble Yes, I just got distracted :) The deets aren't as juicy as one might like, but I'll do what I can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally got around to refactoring some of the election views to use a partial for the nomination menus instead of having the markup written out explicitly in three different places. And in the process, I ended up introducing a null reference exception for non-moderator users - it was when we look up pending flags on a nomination. Whoops. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The fix is out in production. Thanks for the report!